# XMLl schema RegEx character class

Tags: regex, xml

I know that [abc] can be used to match a or b or c but how can it be made to match a and b and c or indeed any permutation?

What I'm really trying to do is with words. i.e [(one)(two)(three)(four)(five)] and I need an expression that will allow, all or some of the words to be allowed?

Can this be done with Eclipse XML schema?

TY

C

Comment: A quantifier `[...]{1,n}` (where `n` is the number of characters in a character class) will match all permutations of the characters in a character class.  Are your needs more complicated than this?

Comment: No, I think what I'm trying to do is fairly simple - it was just the correct syntax that eluded me the "{1,n}" -ty

Comment: Huh, really? That doesn't sound like what you were asking to me!

Comment: It guess my comment answered your question somehow, but I agree with @TomLord that it does not sound like the (complete) answer to what you seemed to be asking; and I sense that you may have had a very interesting question with some clarification. What inputs/results do you expect? What is the connection (if any) between your comment about permutations of *character* elements (e.g. `a`, `b`, and `c`) vs. your comment about permutations of *string* elements (e.g. `one`, `two`, `three` etcetera)? As it stands, your question begs to be closed as unlikely to benefit anyone.

Comment: I have one section where the customer can ultimately choose from 10 options from a list of requirements. I need them, or at least the resulting XML document, to reflect this. I realised that enumeration onlys allow one option of 10 to be chosen. I thought that a regex would work but was unsure of how exactly to go about it. As far as I now understand that can be done by: [(one)(two)(three) ..etc(ten)]{1,10}? I haven't yet tried it though. The words in the brackets allude to different options for processing. The customer must be able to choose at least one, or 10.Does this clarify?